# AngularJs how run all request in forEach together?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have 40 requests to be executed, but it is very slow. How can all of them be run together in async.

```
  angular.forEach($rootScope.aliexpressModel.items.item, function (item, index) {
                        repositoryService.getByParams("api/AliExpress/Download", { url: item.pic_url })
                        .then(function (res) {
                            $rootScope.aliexpressModel.items.item[index].downloadUrl = res.data;
                        })
                    });
```

Comment: They already executed together in async.

Comment: But when these requests are running. I want to run another application and it waits for previous requests to run

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `$q.all`.

```
var promiseArray = [];
angular.forEach($rootScope.aliexpressModel.items.item, function (item, index) {
  promiseArray.push(repositoryService.getByParams("api/AliExpress/Download", { url: item.pic_url }));
});

$q.all(promiseArray)
then(function(response) {
  for(var i=0;i< response.length;i++) {
    $rootScope.aliexpressModel.items.item[i].downloadUrl = response[i].data;
  }
});
```

Comment: when these requests are running. I want to run another application and it waits for previous requests to run

Comment: @HadiJahangiri async doesn't mean parallel. You either run it before or after the execution of all your callbacks